# how to innerHTML a content of pre tag

Tags: javascript, ftp

Hi I have a FTP site on my browser like ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/clim_data/IDCKWCDEA0/tables/stations_db.txt

I am trying to get the text inside the pre tag using 
document.getElementsByTagName('pre').innerHTML it is returning udefined.
Is someone can tell me why I cannot get the content of the

```
`<html><head><link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines"></head><body><pre>015590  NT  15B   ALICE SPRINGS AIRPORT                    19400101..      -23.7951 133.889   
014272  NT  14GA  BATCHELOR AIRPORT                        19920813..      -13.0545 131.0252  
014723  NT  14DE  BORROLOOLA AIRPORT                       19871107..      -16.0755 136.3041  
014954  NT  14GA  BRADSHAW                                 19980529..      -14.9408 130.8092  
014627  NT  14DE  BULMAN                                   20021010..      -13.6714 134.3414  
014909  NT  14GA  CENTRAL ARNHEM PLATEAU                   20030731..      -13.3275 133.0861  
014703  NT  14DE  CENTRE ISLAND                            19680101..      
  </pre>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array, not a single element. You need to specify which element of the fetched elements you want to modify. Try with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML
```

Alternatively, a better solution would be to give that `pre` an id, so that you can target it precisely (because it might happen, that the `pre` won't be the first element fetched as I assumed by using `[0]`)

```
document.getElementById('pre-element').innerHTML
```

Comment: It isn't an array, it is an HTML Collection. It's array-like in many ways, but isn't an array.